# Small operators in Hahn fields

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $H=K((G))$ be a Hahn field over $K$ with monomial group $G$. Let $D$ be a K-vector subspace of $K((G))$ such that if $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ ($I$ possibly infinite) is a sequence in $D$ such that $\sum_{i\in I} a_i \in H$, then $\sum_{i\in I} a_i \in D$.

Call $P:D\rightarrow D$ *small* if there is $R\subset G$ with $R$ bounded above by 1 such that for all $s\in D$ we have that $supp(P(s)) \subseteq R \ supp(s)$ where $supp(s)$ stands for the support of $s$ as a function from $G$ to $K$.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007201000355 (1.3)

Is there any literature on this kinds of operators? Do they have another name?